# Kalman filter matrix dimensions mismatch

Tags: java, kalman-filter

I have created following dimensional matrices for a Kalman Filter:

- **Matrix `X`**, the state matrix: `4x1`, which has: `[X; dX; Y; dY]`

  - `X`: x-coordinate
  - `dX`: rate of changing x-coordinate
  - `Y`: x-coordinate
  - `dY`: rate of changing y-coordinate.
- **Matrix `H`**, the observation matrix: `2x4`
- **Matrix `R`**, the measurement noise covariance matrix: `2x4`.
- **Matrix `Z`**, the measurement matrix: `4x1` since there are `4` measurements for states.

But apparently there is a mismatch of matrix dimensions as apache Kalman filter throws matrix dimension mismatch exception.

I'm slightly confused with creating matrices suitable to a measurement matrix (`Z`) of `4x1` and state matrix of `4x1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/filter/KalmanFilter.html) it's either your control vector or your measurement vector, which has an incorrect size.

There are 2 cases where that exception can be thrown.

Case predict: DimensionMismatchException - if the dimension of the control vector does not match

Case correct: DimensionMismatchException - if the dimension of the measurement vector does not fit

There are few cases, but [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-math3/3.0/org/apache/commons/math3/filter/KalmanFilter.java#343) it is due to number of rows of matrix R being not equal to number of rows of z.

Comment: It's in the filter.correct(). It was due to mismatching the number of rows of R and dimensions of z. They has to be equal according to the source. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-math3/3.0/org/apache/commons/math3/filter/KalmanFilter.java#343

Comment: The actual answer would be much appreciated here

Answer (score 1):

if H is 2x4, then R should be 2x2, and z should be 2x1